# Confusion regarding char[]

Tags: c++

I have recently started programming in C++ and that's why I am facing lots of confusions.
I wanted to know what's wrong in using the following piece of code:

```
char interface[20];
interface="USB01";
```

Comment: Try using `std::string`

Comment: Though for C, the above question with its answers apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ language does not allow you to assign to arrays.

You can, however, initialize arrays. The syntax is similar, but the assignment operator is used in the same statement as the declaration:

```
char interface[20] = "USB01";
```

However, in C++, one would typically use a standard container like `std::string` rather than C strings. These are far easier to use and do allow for natural assignments.

```
std::string interface;
....
interface = "USB01";
```

Note that we don't need to decide up front how much space to reserve for the string. This is just one of the many benefits of using the standard string class.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out and i will keep your point in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *assign* arrays like that, but you can *initialise* them:

```
 char interface[20] = "USB01";
```

In C++ though you should be using proper C++ strings, i.e. `std::string`, not C-style `char *` strings:

```
 std::string interface;

 interface = "USB01";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer things got pretty clear now. Another small question -> Suppose we have a declaration as " char BitmapNameF[512]; "in a header file and i have included it in y program. so now how do i pass a value to BitmapNameF?

Comment: @SkRuddy: if you have a further question then please post it as a new question - comments aren't really a good way to deal with additional questions and answers.

Comment: Sure i'll post a new question.